# Unstable internet connection after Ubuntu 20 update

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager, internet

I have an Ubuntu laptop and I am using a wireless adapter to connect over to a wifi.
The problem is that the internet connection keeps dropping off every 5 or 10 minutes but the problem is not the internet itself, as I can continue using it on two smartphones and a windows laptop, while the internet is dead in my Ubuntu laptop.

I have had this issue a while ago when using Ubuntu 19, and apearently the adapter firmware is very buggy with current linux kernel, so I found a solution by replacing the firmware files for the wifi adapter and everything worked very well.

But last week I decided to update to Ubuntu 20 and the problem returned, tried doing the same steps with different firmwares but I can't get it to work this time.

I currently tried the firmware solution mentioned, but I also tried limiting the band to 2.4 Ghz as opposed to leaving it automatic and also limiting the MTU size to 1400, but nothing seems to work.

It is worth noting that this problem does not happen in every wifi connection, 2 weeks ago I was connected to a different wifi and this problem didn't show up.

When the internet connection dies, If I just reconnect to the wifi, it comes back up, but as you would imagine, 5-10 minutes later it dies again. If I wait some time it comes back naturally and sometimes it even disconnects from the wifi.

My network adapter is as follows:

```
  *-network        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:9a:37:c9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00075 ip=192.168.0.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:160 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19.  There was Ubuntu 19.04 and Ubuntu 19.10.  Which were you referring to?  Since 19.04, 19.10, and 20.04 are three separate versions with different software contained within it is rather difficult to provide a correct answer without knowing what you were running and are running now.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I was at 19.04 and update to 20.04